# Sort chained objects with parent

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

we have Lists of categories where each category can has parent field which is reference to parent category of current category. Can you tell me what is the best algorithm in java to sort categories, for instance from top to bottom category? Thank you.

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Category {
     @Id
     Long id;
     @ManyToOne
     Category parent;
}
```

Sample:

List of:

- Category(id=3, parent=Category(id=11))
- Category(id=4, parent=Category(id=3))
- Category(id=11, parent=Category(id=20, parent=null))

will sorted from top to bottom like that:

**Category(id=20) -> Category(id=11) -> Category(id=3) -> Category(id=4)**

[image]

Comment: Give a concrete example. Do you want to sort a list or the chain parent-child-grandchiled-... ? provide a small Example and the deired result. Also mention what you have tried so far.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I'm sorry .. I added it for better understanding

Comment: I see no sorting in your example. You simply listed the categories in the order already defined by the parent-relation.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I also added image. I need some logic, which effectively create order of cattegories like you can see on image. From highest parent to lowest child

Comment: Are you looking for [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you've List. You can sort that list using Collections.sort();
But your class has to change a little bit, because you've to implement Comparable and override compareTo() method. This is an example,  I hope it helps you.

```
public class Category implements Comparable<Category>{
    Long id;
    Category parent;
    // Constructors getters setters
    public int compareTo(Category aux){
       // Assuming you want to sort by parent's id, and I understand a category
       // maybe doesn't have parent it may be null
       if(aux.getParent() != null && this.parent != null){
           if(aux.getParent().getId() > this.parent.getId()) return -1;
           else if(aux.getParent().getId() < this.parent.getId()) return ;
           return 0;
       }
       if(aux.getParent() == null && this.parent.getId() == null) return 0;
       if(aux.parent() == null) return 1;
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: He can also use a `Comparator` instead of implementing `Comparable`, if he does not want to change the class.

Comment: True, it's another option.

Comment: I cannot count with id size, I update question with example what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how sorting is involved here.

1. Search for the category that has no parent
2. search for the child of it
3. goto 2

This gives you the list you want.

**Remark:**
If every parent has only one or no child you get a list like in your example. (or more than one list) otherwise you get a tree (or more than one tree).

In case of "one or no child" you can extend your category by a field `child` which makes it a double linked list. In this case "search for the child of it" gets trivial since you have a direct reference to it.